# Home page loop once, other pages loop through all

Tags: forloop

I only want one block on the home page, other pages can loop through all of them. Is there a more efficient way to write this?

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment(1) is empty %}
        {% for block in memberships.memberships.limit(1) %}
        <a href="{{ block.urlLocation }}" class="center" target="_blank">
            {% for asset in block.logo %}
                <img src="{{ asset.url('memberships')}}" alt="{{ asset.title }}" />
            {% endfor %}
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
        {% for block in memberships.memberships %}
        <a href="{{ block.urlLocation }}" class="center" target="_blank">
            {% for asset in block.logo %}
                <img src="{{ asset.url('memberships')}}" alt="{{ asset.title }}" />
            {% endfor %}
        </a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
{% set blockLimit = entry.section.isHomepage() ? 1 : null %}

{% for block in memberships.memberships.limit(blockLimit) %}
  <a href="{{ block.urlLocation }}" class="center" target="_blank">
    {% for asset in block.logo %}
      <img src="{{ asset.url('memberships')}}" alt="{{ asset.title }}" />
    {% endfor %}
  </a>
{% endfor %}
```

`entry.section` returns the [SectionModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/sectionmodel) for the entry, and `isHomepage()` tells you whether that section is the homepage. Then you set your `limit` accordingly.

Comment: Great answer! The only change I'd make is setting `limit = (entry.section.isHomepage() ? 1 : null)` beforehand (simply for code legibility). It may also be necessary on pages where `entry` is not defined.

Comment: freaking sweet!

Comment: @LindseyD totally right about the code legibility. I will edit my answer